# Is this how message queues are supposed to work?

Tags: c, unix, message-queue

I am trying to understand message queues. In the examples I saw, the `msg` strunct would have only one more attribute except of the first one (the type) which must be `long`. So, it would be something like `struct msg{long mtype; char text[100]};`.

I tried to add a new `int` attribute, `x` to see if I recieve both the text and the number and it worked.

Is this how message queues are supposed to work? Can I have as many attributes as I want in my `struct`?

And, also, is it ok to call the `msgrcv` and `msgsnd` functions with the length parameter set to `sizeof(send) - sizeof(send.x)` because I know that the sizeof a struct isn't always the same as the sum of the `sizeof` of each attribute?
Thank you.

```
int main(){

    struct msg{
        long mtype;
        char text[100];
        int x;
    };

    int key = ftok(".", 10);
    int qid = msgget(key, 0666|IPC_CREAT);

    int pid = fork();

    if(pid == 0){
        struct msg send;
        send.mtype = 1;
        strcpy(send.text, "hello");
        send.x = 99;
        if(msgsnd(qid, (void*)&send, sizeof(send) - sizeof(send.x), 0)<0){
             printf("Error child: ");
        }
    }
    else{
        struct msg recieve;
        if(msgrcv(qid, (void*)&recieve, sizeof(recieve) - sizeof(recieve.x), 1, 0)<0){
             perror("Error parent: ");
        };
        printf("text: %s\nnumber: %d", recieve.text, recieve.x);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The char[] is just a placeholder, you can have whatever you want in the structure after the required long mtype field. The size on the msgsnd() call does NOT include mtype.

You almost had it correct.

Here is a working version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/msg.h>

int main(void){

    struct msg {
        long mtype;
        char text[100];
        int x;
    };

    size_t sz = sizeof(struct msg) - sizeof(long);  <=== /* SIZE */
    int key = ftok(".", 10);
    int qid = msgget(key, 0666|IPC_CREAT);

    int pid = fork();

    if (pid == 0){
        struct msg send;
        send.mtype = 1;
        strcpy(send.text, "hello");
        send.x = 99;
        if (msgsnd(qid, (void*)&send, sz, 0)<0){
             perror("Error child: ");
        }
    } else {
        struct msg recieve;
        if(msgrcv(qid, (void*)&recieve, sz, 1, 0)<0){
             perror("Error parent: ");
        };
        printf("text: %s\nnumber: %d\n", recieve.text, recieve.x);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I can't see the difference between your version and mine. Your size_t sz = sizeof(struct msg) - sizeof(long) is the equivalent of my sizeof(recieve) - sizeof(recieve.x). Am I missing something?

Comment: It's only numerically "equivalent" if an `int` and a `long` are the same size.

Comment: Semantically, it is correct to subtract the size of the `mtype`. It is not correct to subtract off some field you want to send (like `x`).

Answer (score 4):

From the [man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/msgsnd.2.html), in:

```
int msgsnd(int msqid, const void *msgp, size_t msgsz, int msgflg);
```

`msgp` is defined as:

> The msgp argument is a pointer to a **caller-defined** structure of the
>          following general form:
>
> ```
>       struct msgbuf {
>            long mtype;       /* message type, must be > 0 */
>            char mtext[1];    /* message data */
>        };
> ```

***Bold*** is mine

The major point here being the struct is *caller-defined*. So as long as the input struct (sent by `msgsnd`) and output struct (received by `msgrcv`) are the same, the data following `mtype` can be anything you want (as long as you specify the size correctly). For your case, you really only need:

```
msgsnd(qid, (void*)&send, sizeof(send) - sizeof(send.mtype), 0)
```

and

```
msgrcv(qid, (void*)&recieve, sizeof(recieve) - sizeof(send.mtype), 1, 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int msgsnd(int msqid, const void *msgp, size_t msgsz, int msgflg);
```

Since the `msgp` parameter is declared as `const void*`, you can use whatever data type you want. There is nothing that says it has to be a `struct` with just a `long` and a `char[]`. This means you can just do `sizeof(send)`. You do not need to adjust for the extra struct member that you are sending. In fact, doing so will cause problems because the entire struct will not be handled. The only thing that matters is that `msgrcv()` uses the same struct as the previous `msgsnd()`. See [this example](http://tldp.org/LDP/lpg/node35.html).

Comment: The `char[]` is just a placeholder, you can have whatever you want in the structure after the required `long mtype` field.  The size on the `msgsnd()` call does NOT include `mtype`.

Comment: @JohnHascall Is `mtype` required?

Comment: Yes the struct must begin with a `long` for the message type.  You don't have to call it `mtype` but that's the normal practice.